# 2 network interfaces but can't access server publicly

Tags: networking, 16.04, apache2, virtualhost, static-ip

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and 2 Network Interfaces. 
Workers can't access this server from internet only accessible LAN. 
My second network card configure with static ip address.
Subdomain redirect to this static ip address. 
I added an A record for this static IP at my hosting server.
DNS server also installed at this server

#

network configuration is

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address 192.168.x.x
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.x.0
        broadcast 192.168.x.255
        gateway 192.168.x.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 192.168.x.1 192.168.x.5
        dns-search domain.org.pk
## Interface configuration for Nexlinx connection
auto eno2
**iface eno2 inet static**
        address 116.x.x.x
        netmask 255.255.255.x
        broadcast 116.x.x.x
        gateway 116.x.x.153
        dns-nameservers 116.x.x.x 202.x.x.x
```

What setting required to accessible server publicly?
When I installed Ubuntu 16 server I set primary address 192.168.x.x. Can I change static ip address secondary to primary? how?

Comment: Please, can you give us output from command `route -n`

Comment: @2707974                Kernel IP routing table
--- Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
116.58.137.152  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eno2
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1

Answer (score 1):

Based on output of your `route -n` command, your default gateway is set to `192.186.10.1` aka `eno1` interface. Because of that your server in not Public accessible. You can change via changing metric for default routes.

Metric can change on several place. Best working for me is configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eno0
iface eno0 inet static
    address 192.168.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.x.0
    broadcast 192.168.x.255
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.x.1 192.168.x.5
    dns-search domain.org.pk
    up route add default gw 192.168.x.1 metric 10

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 116.x.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.x
    broadcast 116.x.x.x
    gateway 116.x.x.153
    dns-nameservers 116.x.x.x 202.x.x.x
```

On this way we add `metric 10` to the `eno0` interface and on is now second best. Primary route is on `eno1`. 
After this changes restart networking.

```
 systemctl restart networking.service
```

Now `route -n` will be different.

NOTE: If you communicate via `eno0` only with `192.168.x.x` network you do not need gateway on that interface. I mean, you can simple delete gateway from `eno0` interface setup.

Comment: not working after suggested changes still not accessible internet

Comment: Please give me output from `route -n`, before and after changes.

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
roun -n output after your suggested changes....

Comment: Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
116.58.127.152  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eno2
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1

Comment: before changes.....Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface 0.0.0.0 192.168.10.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eno1 116.58.137.152 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.248 U 0 0 0 eno2 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 eno1

Comment: Can you please do `tarceroute 8.8.8.8` after changes. This will give a path of packet

Comment: Based on this, your traffic go to gateway 192.168.10.1. When you do changes?

Comment: I didn't any change after your suggested changes

Comment: Somehow your default gw is still 192.168.10.1. After changes do you do `sudo service networking restart` ?